# CRUD - enviar id da linha selecionada para toolbar - CakePHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, cakephp, crud

estou me batendo à um tempinho com o seguinte problema:

Montei um CRUD no CakePHP, fiz o grid com css pra ficar legal e pronto. O problema é que não é nada elegante ter uma coluna de ações e os botões de "Visualizar", "Adicionar", "Promover" e "Recusar" aparecendo em todas as linhas nesta coluna. Então criei uma toolbar bacana e chego no meu problema, não consigo passar o valor do id da linha para o link da toolbar usando checkbox ou radio. Segue abaixo o html da tabela, aguardo um help.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<table class="tabela-crud">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <TH colspan="9">Solicitação de Produtos</TH>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="9" style='text-align: left;'>
               <?php echo $this->Html->link( "Visualizar", array('action'=>'view'), array('class' => 'btn-crud') ); ?>
               <?php echo $this->Html->link( "Editar", array('action'=>'edit'), array('class' => 'btn-crud') ); ?>
               <?php echo $this->Html->link( "Nova", array('action'=>'add'), array('class' => 'btn-crud') ); ?>                
            </th>

        </tr>   
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style='width: 1px;'>            
            </th>
            <th ><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id', 'ID');?>  </th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('codigo_produto', 'Código');?>  </th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('codigo_pedido', 'Pedido');?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('data_pedido', 'Emissão Pedido');?></th>              
        </tr>
        <?php $count=0; ?>
        <?php foreach($produtos as $produto): ?>                
        <?php $count ++;?>
        <?php if($count % 2): echo '<tr>'; else: echo '<tr class="zebra">' ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input type='radio' id='r-<?php echo $produto['Produto']['id']; ?>'name='id-radio' value='<?php echo $produto['Produto']['id']; ?>'>
    </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $produto['Produto']['id']; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $produto['Produto']['codigo_produto'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><?php if($produto['Produto']['codigo_pedido'] === null){echo ' - ';}else{ echo $produto['Produto']['codigo_pedido']; } ?></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><?php if($produto['Produto']['data_pedido']  === null){echo ' - ';}else{ echo $produto['Produto']['data_pedido']; }?></td>
    </tr>               
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($produto); ?>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: Você já tentou mudar ou adicionar o parâmetro nos links da toolbar?

Comment: Da uma lida na documetação http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link

Comment: Sim Marcos, havia dado uma lida no helper Html só que não consegui pensar numa solução rsrs mas agora to estudando pesado a documentação. E Jefferson sim, eu até tentei usando um pco de Jquery, mas minha dificuldade é capturar o parâmetro para colocar no link. Mas vlw ajuda galera, o José Marcos ali me deu uma boa ideia, usando hidden, vou tentar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente colocar dentro do hidden os Id's de sua tabela e depois passar os valores via post com o nome do campo.